# How to update UI from a new thread vb.NET website

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, web-applications

My application works like this:

- Upload Excel file + convert to `DataTable`
- Start new thread
- Begin loop through `DataTable`

  - **Update UI (`Label`) to show "Processing row [i] of [n]"**
  - Next
- End loop

The bold is what I'm not able to do.  I've looked around online for updating UI elements from worker threads, but all the results I can seem to find are for Windows Forms, rather than a web project. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using jQuery AJAX and asp.NET `WebMethod`s and a session variable.

I used a method from one of my previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540957/jquery-ajax-loop-to-refresh-jqueryui-progressbar), by having a `WebMethod` check on a Session variable that was updated by the worker thread.

Worker thread:

```
Session["progress"] = "{\"current\":" + (i + 1) + ", \"total\":" + dt.Rows.Count + "}"
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetProgress()
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["progress"] == null) {
        return "{\"current\":1,\"total\":1}";
    } else {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["progress"];
    }
}
```

my jQuery basically looped calling that AJAX WebMethod every second.  It would start on page load and if the `current = total` then it would display "Completed" and clear the loop, otherwise it shows "Processing row [current] of [total]".  I even added a [jQuery UI Progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

This is kind of a manual solution but it solves my problem, with little overhead.  An unexpected but nice piece is that since it is utilizing a Session variable, and the WebMethod checks on page load, if the worker thread is active then the progressbar will show even if you navigate away and come back to the page.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it, and actually it is not difficult. you can use ajax toolbox to do it easily. simply use an updatepanel, and update progress.

check http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

an example: http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/updateprogressoverview.aspx

Comment: I am aware of the `UpdatePanel`/`UpdateProgress` controls, but have run into too many problems with them in the past.  I also can't seem to find a way to tell the `UpdateProgress` control a specific value to display (like in my requirement "Processing row [i] of [n]"