# jquery ajax call to update progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to update a jquery progress bar value with the value of percentage complete of a particular process. Basically i have the following function:

```
function updateProgressBar() {

$.ajax({
    url: "WebService/DataServices.asmx/getPercentage",
    dataType: "text",
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    success: function (value) {
        $("#progress2").html(value);          
        $("#progress-sample").progressbar({
            value: parseInt(value)
        });
    }
});
}
```

the function basically make an ajax request to a webmethod getPercentage which calculates the percentage completed. the function is then called every 5 seconds using

```
$(document).ready(setInterval(updateProgressBar, 5000));
```

For some reason the progress bar value is not being set when the web app is run. I added a `div` with id `progress2` and the value is reflected successfully however not the progressbar value. When setting the progress bar value hardcoded it works fine though. Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you are using some plugin, what is the plugin name? i am asking just to verify that the plugin doesn't have a unique way to update the progress bar's value

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474528/showing-progressbar-progress-with-ajax-request and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540957/jquery-ajax-loop-to-refresh-jqueryui-progressbar

Comment: @RachelGallen thanks however i didnt find my solution in those questions. the issue reported there is different. my issue is that the progress value is always being 0.

Comment: I think you mean: `$(document).ready(function(){ setInterval(updateProgressBar, 5000) });`